# How do I use fetchColumn()?

Tags: php

```
public function checkForeignKey($aId) {
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cursusleerling WHERE cursusid = ?");
    $statement->bindValue(1, $aId); 
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchColumn() > 0;
}
```

This can either return true or false, but how do I check for that value?

Comment: What exactly you want to know??

Comment: What about: $result=$statement->fetchColumn(); then return $result; ? I'm not posting as an answer, because I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It will return the number of selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing

```
return $statement->fetchColumn() > 0;
```

will evaluate to an expression, checking *is the column greater than zero*, so you get a boolean `true`/`false` returned; `true` if the count is greater than zero, `false` otherwise.

If you just return `$statement->fetchColumn()` instead, without checking `> 0`, you will get the exact count back instead of a boolean. Since PHP is weak/loosely typed, expressions such as `1 == true` is true*, you can use the result in an if-statement too, like this

```
public function checkForeignKey($aId) {
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cursusleerling WHERE cursusid = ?");
    $statement->bindValue(1, $aId); 
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchColumn(); // removed > 0
}

/* Class defined and such above, using it below */

$obj = new YourClass(..); /* We only see a method of your class, not the whole thing, so just using some psudocode */
$count_result = $obj->checkForeignKey(1337);
if ($count_result) {
    echo "The result was ".$count_result;
} else {
    echo "No results returned";
}
```

* while in strongly typed languages, `1 == true` is false. You can get a strict comparison `1 === true` (three equalities), which is false in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
return $statement->fetchColumn() > 0;
```

this line is check the column count, so it return true or false.

```
return $statement->fetchColumn();
```

it returns num of columns